# How to use an optional order parameter in a query using Typescript and TypeORM

Tags: typescript, graphql, typeorm, typegraphql

I'm using the most recent version of Graphql, Typescript, type-graphql and TypeORM.
I set up basic CRUD and now want to add the functionality to optionally sort the output of my query to get all products.

This is the function I'm working on. Currently I hard coded that it sorts by the name in ascending order, which works fine. But I want to make the property and the sort direction to depend on the user input, which I defined in the Sorting interface. The following error appears when I try to make use of the sorting parameter (e.g. sorting.parameter)

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(this: ObjectType<Product>, options?: FindManyOptions<Product> | undefined): Promise<Product[]>', gave the following error.
    Type '{ sorting: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ name?: "ASC" | "DESC" | 1 | -1 | undefined; id?: "ASC" | "DESC" | 1 | -1 | undefined; tags?: "ASC" | "DESC" | 1 | -1 | undefined; createdAt?: "ASC" | "DESC" | 1 | -1 | undefined; }'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'sorting' does not exist in type '{ name?: "ASC" | "DESC" | 1 | -1 | undefined; id?: "ASC" | "DESC" | 1 | -1 | undefined; tags?: "ASC" | "DESC" | 1 | -1 | undefined; createdAt?: "ASC" | "DESC" | 1 | -1 | undefined; }'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(this: ObjectType<Product>, conditions?: FindConditions<Product> | undefined): Promise<Product[]>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ order: { sorting: string; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FindConditions<Product>'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'order' does not exist in type 'FindConditions<Product>'.
```

```
import { Service } from 'typedi';
import { Product } from '../entity/Product';
import { CreateProductInput, UpdateProductInput } from '../../schema/products';

interface Sorting {
  parameter: "name" | "created_at",
  direction: "ASC" | "DESC"
}

@Service()
export class ProductService {
  getAll = async (sorting? : Sorting): Promise<Product[]> => {
    if (sorting) {
// tried using ({order: {sorting.parameter : sorting.direction}});
      return Product.find({order: {name : "ASC"}});
    }
    return Product.find();
  };
.
.
.
}
```

The product entity is defined as follows:

```
import {
    Entity,
    PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
    Column,
    BaseEntity,
    CreateDateColumn,
  } from 'typeorm';

//   import {Tag} from './Tag'
  
  @Entity()
  export class Product extends BaseEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id!: number;
  
    @Column()
    name!: string;
  
    // @OneToMany(type => Tag, tag => tag.name)
    // @Column({ type: () => [Tag]})
    @Column({ type: 'text', array: true })
    tags!: string[];
  
    @CreateDateColumn({ name: 'created_at' })
    createdAt!: Date;
  }
```

My resolver looks like this.

```
import { Query, Resolver, Mutation, Arg } from 'type-graphql';
import { Service } from 'typedi';
import { Product, CreateProductInput, UpdateProductInput } from '../schema/products';
import { ProductService } from '../database/services/productService';

@Service()
@Resolver(() => Product)
export class ProductResolver {
  constructor(private readonly productService: ProductService) {}

  @Query(() => [Product], { nullable: true })
  async getProducts(
    @Arg('sorting', {nullable: true})  inputParameter: "name" | "created_at",
    @Arg('direction', {nullable: true, defaultValue: "ASC"}) inputDirection: "ASC" | "DESC"): Promise<Product[]> {
    return this.productService.getAll({parameter: inputParameter, direction: inputDirection});
  }
```

Comment: please share minimum reproducable example in ts playground. Only function wich uses Sorting interface is important

Answer (score 0):

I made it work with this:

```
getAll = async (sorting? : Sorting): Promise<Product[]> => {
    if (sorting?.parameter === "createdAt") {
      return Product.find({order: {createdAt : sorting.direction}});
    } else if (sorting?.parameter === "name") {
      return Product.find({order: {name : sorting.direction}});
    }
    return Product.find();
  };
```

So I split the 2 potential properties I'm expecting into if clauses, instead of accessing the sorting.properties once. A little bit ugly since I would have to adjust it whenever something changes, but I'm not sure it can be avoided it this setup.

The problem is that I tried to set "someKey" to a string in this format: Product.find(order: {someKey : someValue}), but it only accepts they keys of my entity